# cache database query in application server

Tags: mysql, spring, jdbctemplate

I had webapps using spring jdbc template and now , want to improve performance of my application , so i want to cache result of some DATABASE QUERY in my Tomcat server.How i can achieve dis concept.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Spring 3.1 has introduced a Caching Abstraction. You should be able to make use of this to cache the results of your DAO method calls.

The documentation is [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html) and it was included in the Spring blog [here](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/23/spring-3-1-m1-caching/).

Comment: thanks for reply ...Please give an example or link from which i could implement.

Comment: There are a few examples out there but not a huge number because it's a fairly new feature. Have you read the documentation already? What have you tried since reading it? Post your code and any errors if you're stuck.

Comment: http://www.brucephillips.name/blog/index.cfm/2011/3/22/Spring-31-Cache-Implementation-With-Cacheable-and-CacheEvict-Annotations

Answer (score 0):

I have it working, but Alex is correct, there are a few different ways to configure this, depending on what you want as your Caching backend.

For cache configuration, I've selected ehcache, as it's simple to configure, but has powerful features for configuring ttl/etc.

Configuration:

```
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">

    <cache:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
        <property name="cacheManager"><ref local="ehcache"/></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean"
          p:configLocation="classpath:ehcache.xml"/>

</beans>
```

ehcache.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd"
    updateCheck="false" monitoring="autodetect"
    dynamicConfig="true">

<!-- http://ehcache.org/documentation/configuration.html -->
<!-- Also See org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean -->

    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>
    <cache name="resourceBundle"
           overflowToDisk="false"
           eternal="false"
           maxElementsInMemory="500"
           timeToIdleSeconds="86400"
           timeToLiveSeconds="86400"/>

</ehcache>
```

I had issues with running the ehcache 2.5 in my junit environment, due to caches with duplicate names running concurrently was not allowed, and they didn't seem to shut down right away, but here is my pom entry:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

Finally, on your repository, do the following:

```
@Repository
public class someStore {
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    //The value here needs to match the name of the cache configured in your ehcache xml.  You can also use Spel expressions in your key
    @Cachable(value = "resourceBundle", key = "#basename+':'+#locale.toString()")
    public ResourceBundle getResourceBundle(final String basename, final Locale locale){
        ...
    }

    @CacheEvict(value = "resourceBundle", key = "#basename+':'+#locale.toString()")
    public void revertResourceBundle(final String basename, final Locale locale){
        ...
    }
}
```